# Finding pattern in Python

Tags: python, function

I have a file. I want to create a pattern. Then, I will calculate some values. I am using code below. How can I split these 3 values? Also, there white spaces in some columns as below pic.

```
title=movies[3].split(",")[1]

title

pattern=r"(\d+)[(\d+)-(\d+)]"

import re
re.findall(pattern,title)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape the characters `[` and `]`. Now it is seen as a definition of the defined set of characters between those brackets.

Change your regular expression to:

```
pattern = r"(\d+)\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]"
```

To add optional whitespaces to the regular expression you can use `\s*`. So the full regular expression would be

```
pattern = r"(\d+)\[\s*(\d+)-(\d+)\s*\]"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking specifically for the `-` character, you will need to escape it using `\`, as this will make the expression look for the character instead of using it for its other usage of defining a range.

This means your new pattern should look like: `(\d+)[(\d+)\-(\d+)]`

As a side-note, I can recommend using [regex101](https://regex101.com) to double-check your patterns before using them!

---

Adding Matthias' answer onto here. If the square brackets are part of the title, you will also want to escape them too like so: `(\d+)\[(\d+)\-(\d+)\]`

This will look for two values separated by a hyphen, within square brackets.